# General formula for polynomials defined recursively

Tags: polynomials

Let $a_1(x)=x$.

Now define polynomials recursively by

$a_n(x):=a_{n-1}(x)\cdot(a_{n-1}(x)-1)$.

Is there a general formula for these polynomials, or a name?

$a_1(x)=x$

$a_2(x)=x^2-x$

$a_3(x)=x^4-2x^3+x$

$a_4(x)=x^8-4x^7+4x^6+2x^5-5x^4+2x^3+x^2-x$

$a_5(x)=x^{16}-8x^{15}+24x^{14}-28x^{13}-10x^{12}+60x^{11}-50x^{10}-14x^9+48x^8-20x^7-14x^6+12x^5+2x^4-4x^3+x$

$\vdots$

Comment: A closely related recursive map is the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I had a feeling I'd seen something similar before, but couldn't think of where! Thanks!

Comment: Also, under the transformation $z\to z+\frac{1}{2}$, the map becomes $f(z)=z^2-3/4$ which closely resembles to that one used for defining the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set)

Comment: Compute a few more examples and look for the verttical sequences of coefficients in OEIS. For instance, the third coefficient seems to follows this: https://oeis.org/A059153